# Idiomatic way to obtain conditional density function from a continuous joint distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, conditional

## Context

In Mathematica one is able to directly calculate the marginal and conditional probability distributions of a **discrete** joint distribution (abstracting over the specific details) like so:

[image]

## Represent joint distribution

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.37,0.17, 0.14, 0.02, 0.24, 0.05} -> {
     {0, 0}, {0, 1}
   , {1, 0}, {1, 1}
   , {2, 0}, {2, 1}
 }];
```

## get Marginal

```
marginal1= PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1] , X]//Simplify
```

## get Conditional

```
conditional = Probability[X == x \[Conditioned] Y ==y, {X,Y} \[Distributed] dist]//Simplify
```

## Plot them

```
joint = PDF[dist, {x, y}];
marginal1 = PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1], x];
marginal2 = PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 2], y];
conditional = Probability[X == x \[Conditioned] Y == y, {X, Y} \[Distributed] dist] // Simplify;


GraphicsGrid[{{DiscretePlot3D[joint, {x, 0, 2}, {y,0, 1}, ExtentSize -> Full, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> "P[X==x,Y==y]"],DiscretePlot3D[joint, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1},ExtentSize -> Full, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 2},PlotLabel -> "P[X==x\[Conditioned]Y==y]"]},{DiscretePlot[marginal1, {x, 0, 2}, ExtentSize -> Full, PlotLabel -> "P[X==x]"],DiscretePlot[marginal2, {y, 0, 1},ExtentSize -> Full, PlotLabel -> "P[Y==y]"]}}]
```

[image]

---

## Question:

I want to know how to calculate the conditional pdf of a **continuous** joint distribution, in a simple **intuitive** way like for the discrete case above.

---

Here is my attempt

## represent Joint distribution

for instance: *uniform distribution over the unit disk*:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{1/\[Pi], 0 <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 1}}],{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
```

[image]

## get Marginal

```
marginal1 = PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1], x] //Simplify
```

[image]

## get Conditional

> ## ?

## What is an idiomatic way to obtain a conditional density function from a continuous joint distribution?

I know I could divide the **Marginal** into the **Joint**, but this does not seem very idiomatic. The master user should not have to waste cognitive power thinking about underlying math. Surely there is some built-in functionality to do this in Mathematica like there is for `Marginal`? Preferably this functionality should take advantage of `Conditional`.

`Likelihood` and `TransformedDistribution`looks like promising alternatives to `Probability` for continuous distributions.

If this desired function does not exist then my questions is: Define this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP considers the Uniform distribution over the unit disc

*i.e.* $(X,Y)$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

[image]

Then, the `Marginal` and `Conditional` functions from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* do what you seek.

The marginal pdf of $Y$ is:

[image]

The conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X = x$ is:

[image]

Comment: hahaha! +1 for being wise master user

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Mathematica provides syntax for extracting conditional `CDF`s from a continuous joint distribution:

This syntax can be used as an intermediate stepping stone to deriving the desired conditional PDF.

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{1/\[Pi], 0 <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 1}}], {x, -1,1}, {y, -1, 1}];
cdf = Probability[X <= x \[Conditioned] Y == y, {X, Y} \[Distributed] dist];
conditionalDensityFunction = PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", cdf}, {x, -1, 1}], x]
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

## update

The comments underneath [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140205/how-to-compute-conditional-probabilities/140212#140212) to a similar question suggests that we are still waiting for this functionality:

[image]

Comment: I think there's something not quite right about the resulting conditional density function.  One gets 0 everywhere when $y=1$ and the area under the density is less that 1.  Don't you want to use `D[cdf, x]` or `conditionalDensityFunction = 
 FullSimplify[
  PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", cdf}, {x, -1, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> -1 < y < 1], x]]` for the conditional density?

Comment: yes, I think your right, I will try and fix it, or replace it with an alternative

Comment: Not to make excuses for *Mathematica* but the domains get more complex, too, besides the form of the density function.  So I can see how it might be difficult to have a general function the spits out conditional densities.